# Difference between ECMAScript 2016 exponentiation operator and Math.pow()

Tags: javascript, exponentiation, ecmascript-2016

What is the benefit to using the ECMAScript 2016 [exponentiation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**)) over the current `Math.pow()`? In other words, besides reducing key strokes, what is the difference between

`Math.pow(2, 2) => 4` and `2 ** 2 => 4`

Comment: From a search around, it appears to be for no other reason than it looks better. There's also the potential for using the `**=` operator too.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

None. As you can read in the ES7 spec, both [`Math.pow`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-math.pow) and the [`**` exponentation operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-exp-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation) cast their arguments/operands to numbers and use the [very same algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-applying-the-exp-operator) to determine the result.

*Addendum*: this changed with the introduction of the BigInt type in ES2020, whose values are only supported by operators (including `**`) but not the `Math` object.

Comment: None *provided that* no one's mucked about with `Math` or `Math.pow`. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party -- I just wanted to add that as much as there is no difference between the two ways, I recently came to realize that the `**` exponentiation operator isn't supported in Internet Explorer, so developers that are interested in extensive **cross-browser support**  for their applications, may prefer to choose the `Math.pow(...)` over the exponentiation operator.[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Math.pow(2,2) === 2**2; // FALSE](https://tech.geekjob.ru/funes8-math-pow-bug/)

```
Math.pow(99,99);
99 ** 99;
```

Result:

3.69729637649726**3e**+197

3.69729637649726**8e**+197

Comment: Either this was fixed since then or it's implementation-dependent, because I just checked in my browser console (Firefox on macOS) and I get the same value for both of those.

Comment: It was fixed. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5848 for example